# Query the total, average and number of large entries by location

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-office

In Access, I have two tables and I have been asked to output some statistics from those tables in to the results of a query.  The trouble is, I have no idea how to do it, or even if it's possible.

The output I'm looking for is as follows -

- **Location** - The individual location from the [Active Directory].[AD Location] field.
- **Count** - A count of each individual location from the [Active Directory].[AD Location] field.
- **Total Mailbox Size** - The sum size of the [IBM Notes].[Notes Mailbox Size] field for each individual location.
- **Average Mailbox Size** - The average size of the [IBM Notes].[Notes Mailbox Size] field for each individual location.
- **Large Mailboxes** - The number of mailboxes from the [IBM Notes].[Notes Mailbox Size] field for each individual location that are larger than 1.5GB

The tables that I need to query are structured thus -

**Table 1 - Active Directory -**

- **Location** - Short text (255).

**Table 2 - IBM Notes -**

- **Mailbox size** - Short text (255) (In the format of "x.xx GB", and unfortunately I cannot change this).

I know how to join the tables and output the **Location** and **Count** fields, but I'm then well and truly lost.  Any hints and tips are appreciated.

Here is what I have so far -

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Active Directory].[AD Location] AS [Location], Count([Active Directory].[AD Location]) AS [Count]
FROM [Active Directory] INNER JOIN [IBM Notes] ON [AD Active Directory].[AD Email Address] = [IBM Notes].[Notes Email Address];
```

And here some example data from the Active Directory and IBM Notes tables, as well as the expected results (each on it's own tab) -

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nvtdxwlr9i82h5c/example.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Thanks, it's saving/running without error.  It is for some reason asking me for a Location though, as opposed to listing all the distinct locations.

Comment: Yep, that was my bad, good spot.  Thanks for the help on this, and on the answer posted by @Hogan.  However, I'm still not quite there, and if you could take a look at the comments on that answer I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this --  I think you get the idea.  I see the in your question that mailbox size is not a number so you will have to covert it to numeric gigabytes.  You'd have to make this change to get it to work.

```
SELECT 
  A.[AD Location] AS [Location], 
  Count(A.[AD Location]) AS [Count],
  SUM(Val(N.[Notes Mailbox Size])) AS [Total Mailbox Size],
  AVG(Val(N.[Notes Mailbox Size])) AS [Average Mailbox Size],
  SUM(IIF(Val(N.[Notes Mailbox Size]) > 1.5,1,0)) AS [Large Mailboxes]
FROM [Active Directory] AS A
INNER JOIN [IBM Notes] AS N ON A.[AD Email Address] = N.[Notes Email Address]
GROUP BY  A.[AD Location]
```

Here is the above statement including checks to ensure that values in the `Notes Mailbox Size` field are not `Null` -

```
SELECT
  A.[AD Location] AS Location,
  Count(A.[AD Location]) AS [Count of Location],
  Sum(IIf(IsNull(N.[Notes Mailbox Size]), "0", Val(N.[Notes Mailbox Size]))) AS [Total Mailbox Size (GB)],
  Round(Avg(IIf(IsNull(N.[Notes Mailbox Size]), "0", Val(N.[Notes Mailbox Size]))), 2) AS [Average Mailbox Size (GB)],
  Sum(IIf(IsNull(N.[Notes Mailbox Size]), "0", IIf(Val(N.[Notes Mailbox Size]) > 2.5, 1, 0))) AS [Count of Large Mailboxs]
FROM [Active Directory] AS A
INNER JOIN [IBM Notes] AS N ON A.[AD Email Address] = N.[Notes Email Address]
GROUP BY A.[AD Location];
```

Comment: @Hogan - Thanks, after a slight change (`IIF` not `IFF`), your statement is producing no errors when I save it.  However, when I run it, I'm being presented with the error **Your query does not include the specified expression 'Location' as part of an aggregate function.**

Comment: @HansUp -- thanks for your suggestions -- I made them.

Comment: @DavidGard - Check out Hans' changes -- I believe they fixed the problem I had with [AD Location] vs Location.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I've also updated my example code as I initially wrote `[Location]`, which is incorrect.  But anyway, we're getting there... Your code saves without errors, however unfortunately I am getting an error - **Data type mismatch in criteria expression.**  This error seems to be in relation to the user of `AVG()` and `SUM()` (which kind of makes sense), suggesting that `Val()` is not returning the expected data type.

Comment: Never mind, I've got it.  I needed to check for Null values when using the maths functions (`SUM` and `AVG`).  Thanks for all the help :)